# Set height and width of background on :hover element

Tags: background, resize, hover, css

I currently have this code

```
#navlogo {
    background: url(img/logo.png);
    background-size: 100px;
    display: block;
    height: 98px;
    width: 98px;
    border-radius: 49px;
}
```

and I want to add this code

```
#navlogo:hover {
    background:url(img/logoblog.png);
    display: block;
    height: 98px;  /* this doesn't work */
    width: 98px;   /* this doesn't work */
}
```

Th original images are 150x150 scaled down and for some reason look better than using 98x98 especially on the iPhone. However, I can't seem to set the background size for the :hover element ....it stays it's original size. I know it can be done with `background-size: 98px 98px;` but this also isn't compatible with IE8 and lower, and CSS3PIE doesn't cover background-size either. is there anyway to do this or do I have to resize the hover picture?

Comment: You're saying that the div changes size on hover? That doesn't make sense. There must be more to the story.

Comment: I think logoblog must be larger than logo and he needs to change the size. However I can't see why there is a problem. If the image is in a div it should work, shouldn't it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the background size from a defined 100px to contain.  If you're changing the div size on hover, then the background size will change with it in that scenario.

*E.G.:*

```
#navlogo {
background: url(img/logo.png);
background-size: **contain**;
display: block;
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
border-radius: 49px;
}

#navlogo:hover {
background:url(img/logoblog.png);
display: block;
height: 98px;               /*this doesn't work*/
width: 98px;                /*this doesn't work*/
}
```

I'm assuming that's what you're going for in this example, as the properties that you're specifying "don't work" in the hover styling are resetting the same values that are present in the normal state styling.  Nothing would change given that they are defined exactly the same.

**EDIT**

If the logoblog image is indeed bigger, setting the background-size property to 'contain' should solve this problem as well.

Comment: I think putting "contain" only into the hovered element might do it.

Comment: This works but will it work with IE as background-size is CSS£ and not  covered by CSS3PIE

Comment: 8 minimum but I would like lower if possible.

Comment: is it possible to solve this problem with IE8 or should I just export a smaller version?

Comment: If you're looking to support eight, you'll need an image for the background which is the actual size you want displayed.  You can still keep the background-size rules, and then simply add an override via [IE Conditional Comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)